# Google Charts Options and Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a javascript function that succesfully draws a line chart using the google charts api.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day In Theater');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Movie 1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Movie 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Movie 3');

    data.addRows([
        [1,   37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,   30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,   25.4, 57, 25.7],
        [4,   11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,   11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6, 7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3, 9.6],
        [8,   12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9,   16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
        [10,   12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11,   5.3, 7.9, 4.7],
        [12,   6.6, 8.4, 5.2],
        [13,   4.8, 6.3, 3.6],
        [14,   4.2, 6.2, 3.4]
    ]);

    // var Series_To_Highlight=1;

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
            subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        series: {
            1: { lineWidth: 5 },
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id='chart' style='width:800px;height:400px;'></div>
```

I am trying to highlight one of the series.
When I hard-code the series I want to highlight, all goes well.

```js
var options = {
    chart: {
        title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
        subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
    },
    series: {
        1: { lineWidth: 5 },
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
};
```

However, when the series I want to highlight is a variable, it doesn't work...

```js
    var Series_To_Highlight=1;

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
            subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        series: {
            Series_To_Highlight: { lineWidth: 5 },
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };
```

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the variable with square braces to interpolate the underlying literal value of `1`.

```js
const Series_To_Highlight = 1;

const options = {
  series: {
    [Series_To_Highlight]: { lineWidth: 5 }
  }
};
```

See: [MDN - Object initializer - Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

> *The object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed and used as the property name. This is reminiscent of the bracket notation of the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) syntax, which you may have used to read and set properties already.*